# Should nested tables have any horizontal space in between them

Tags: html, nested, tablelayout, spacing

I think I have set all padding, margin, border-spacing, etc to 0 but I have a nested table within another table and there is a very tiny (but visible) horizontal space.

I know this as the backcolor of the nested table is blue and the backcolor of the top table is white and I can see a line of white to the right and left of the table.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Don't use nested tables...But what do I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to jump into a philosophical "Anti-Table" debate here, but you might want to step back and reconsider if nesting tables are what you really should be using in this situation...

If you are displaying tabular data and certain cells need to contain multiple rows/columns, you might want to look into using the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes on normal table cells within a single table.

Alternatively, if you're using the tables to render the visual layout of the page, you may want to look into doing it with CSS-based methods.

Comment: can you explain your last sentence ... what css methods could replicate a table format

Comment: Divs and CSS can replace a table.  Multiple divs, floated to one side, with a consistent width and height will do nicely to place boxes of content side by side.  You can create a new "row" by clearing the first div you want in the next row.

Comment: Tables can't be replaced entirelly. They serve a purpose that is showing tabular data and they do it very well. I think nested tables are a good approach when nested tabular data need to be presented, despite the fact that can be seen as a bad contruction.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the **cell-padding** and **cell-spacing** properties of the table to 0

Is that what you meant by

> i think i have set all padding, margin, border-spacing, etc to 0